# How to LEFT JOIN in INFORMIX SQL

Tags: sql, informix

I have the following working sql query for an Informix db.

```
SELECT soi_seq,soi_cusitem,max(soi_product) as ProductCode, 
       max(soi_custprod) as CustProductCode, max(soi_desc) AS ProductDesc, 
       max(soi_comdt2) AS RequiredDate, sum(soi_itqty) as Qty, 
       sum(soi_invval) as Nett, max(soi_discper) as Discount, max(soi_per) 
       as Per, max(soi_price) as ItemPrice 
       from soitem 
       where soi_ordref= ? group by soi_seq,soi_cusitem, soi_lineref 
       order by soi_cusitem asc
```

I need to join to two other tables but dont know how to do this using informix syntax,
basically I need to add to the query above the following joins:

```
       Left Join cmprod on soi_product = cmp_product
       Left Join cmass on cmp_product = cmass_product
```

and also, add the following to the WHERE clause:

```
      AND cmass_assem Is Null
```

I can query and get the required results using an old MS Access connection to the Informix db but not in code.

Comment: ANSI SQL: `select ... from t1 left join t2 on t1.c = t2.d left join t3 on t2.e = t3.f where ... group by ... order by ...`.

Comment: already tried, get System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 'ERROR [42000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A syntax error has occurred.'

Comment: I got round my issue, kept the original query to datatable, created sperate query to datatable then did the required join via linq to datatable. it seems our old version informix doenst support joins.

Comment: Which version of Informix _are_ you using?  If it doesn't support the LEFT JOIN notation, it must be long out of support.

Answer (score 1):

Former versions of Informix use the **outer** keyword as follows:

```
SELECT soi_seq, soi_cusitem, soi_lineref,
       MAX(soi_product) AS ProductCode, 
       MAX(soi_custprod) AS CustProductCode,
       MAX(soi_desc) AS ProductDesc, 
       MAX(soi_comdt2) AS RequiredDate,
       SUM(soi_itqty) AS Qty, 
       SUM(soi_invval) AS Nett,
       MAX(soi_discper) AS Discount,
       MAX(soi_per) AS Per,
       MAX(soi_price) AS ItemPrice 
FROM soitem, -- look, it uses comma to separate tables, even if outer is used
   outer (cmprod CMP, 
   outer cmass CMA)
   -- it requires to order tables with parenthesis
   -- I assume soitem->cmprod->cmass
WHERE 
   -- for good understanding, resolve joins first
   soi_product = CMP.cmp_products 
   AND CMP.cmp_product = CMA.cmass_product 
   -- then match your selection
AND oi_ordref = ?
```

I'm sorry the answer comes a year late, I'll leave it here for future searchers

[Informix outer joins](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/ids_sqt_162.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT soi_seq, soi_cusitem, soi_lineref,
       MAX(soi_product) AS ProductCode, 
       MAX(soi_custprod) AS CustProductCode,
       MAX(soi_desc) AS ProductDesc, 
       MAX(soi_comdt2) AS RequiredDate,
       SUM(soi_itqty) AS Qty, 
       SUM(soi_invval) AS Nett,
       MAX(soi_discper) AS Discount,
       MAX(soi_per) AS Per,
       MAX(soi_price) AS ItemPrice 
FROM soitem
LEFT JOIN cmprod ON soi_product = cmp_product
LEFT JOIN cmass ON cmp_product = cmass_product 
WHERE soi_ordref = ?
      AND cmass_assem IS NULL
GROUP BY 1,2,3 
ORDER BY 2
```